# Audio player for ios <=9 that saves my spot?

Tags: iphone-app, media-player, audiobook

I'm looking for an audio player for ios <=9 (iPhone 4s) that will save my playback spot in each file that I have played. It should also play all of the wav, mp3, m4a, m4b, and flac files on my local device without hassle. I intend to use this for audiobooks so I don't want to start over every time I switch tracks or files. Bookmark support would be cool but not necessary.

Any ideas? Thanks!